# deleting all the nodes in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Anyone know what's wrong with this recrusive function? It doesn't delete all the nodes

```
struct contact
{
    char FirstName[41];
    char LastName[41];
    int id;
    struct contact *next;
};

void ClearList (struct contact *person)
{
    struct contact *temp = person;
    if (person == NULL) return;
    else
    {
        person = person->next;
        free(temp);
        ClearList(person);
    }
}
```

this is my main function

```
void main()
{
    struct contact *person = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    strcpy (person->FirstName, "John");
    strcpy (person->LastName, "Doe");
    person->id = 10;

    person->next = malloc(sizeof(struct contact));
    strcpy (person->next->FirstName, "Will");
    strcpy (person->next->LastName, "Smith");
    person->next->id = 20;
    person->next->next = NULL;

    PrintList(person);
    ClearList(person);
    PrintList(person);
}
```

when I call PrintList after calling ClearList it still prints out some messy stuffs, how do I fix this?

Comment: What is the the definition of `struct contact`?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? And how do you know it doesn't delete all nodes?

Comment: `void ClearList (struct contact *person){ if(person){ClearList(person->next);free(person);}`

Comment: `ClearList(person); PrintList(person);` Used after being released is invalid.

Comment: when i call PrintList again, it prints out the last name and id but the first name is messy

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: While I like the simplicity of your suggestion, I'm doubtful the compiler will be able to tail-recurse it. Leading to ... dare I say it ... stack overflow. The OPs solution, while cumbersome, is tail-recursive.

Answer (score 4):

All the nodes *are* deleted, but you never clear any pointers. So what you're doing is dereferencing invalid pointers leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The `free` function doesn't automatically set pointers to `NULL`.

Comment: so should i put temp = NULL?

Comment: At least this wouldn't be harmfull.

Comment: I think you should set `person` inside the main() to NULL after you do `Clearlist(person);`

Comment: So when deletion happens from last to first then there will be no pointers(next) to clear?? Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like this recursive delete on your linked list. If your linked list has 100 elements you will go 100 functions deep in your stack and probably crash.

I suggest a re-write like this:

```
void ClearList (struct contact *person)
{
   while( person != NULL )
   {
        struct contact * temp = person
        person = person->next;
        free(temp);
   }
}
```

Joachim has the correct answer though. Although we have cleared the memory that person points to, "ClearList" does not have the right to set the original pointer to NULL. So either you need to make ClearList take a double pointer so it can set the pointer to NULL, or just set "person" to NULL after calling ClearList.

Double pointer example, call with ClearList(&person);

```
void ClearList (struct contact ** list)
{
   struct contact *person = *list;
   while( person != NULL )
   {
        struct contact * temp = person
        person = person->next;
        free(temp);
   }
   *list = NULL;
}
```